# Issue with refreshing radio buttons in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

My problem is that I am not able to refresh radio buttons. I have three radio buttons and when i click on any button first time, it works fine. But, when i click on another button then it triggers the event but does not update the buttons visually (previous one remains checked visually). here is my code

```
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
          <legend>Increment:</legend>
          <input type="radio" name="radiob" id="radio1" value="1" class="radio_button"/>
          <label for="radio1">1</label>
          <input type="radio" name="radiob" id="radio2" value="2" class="radio_button" />
          <label for="radio2">2</label>
          <input type="radio" name="radiob" id="radio3" value="3" class="radio_button" />
          <label for="radio3">3</label>
  </fieldset>
```

Here is the jquery code

```
$(".radio_button").change(checkIncrement);

function checkIncrement(){
           $('input:[name=radiob]:radio:checked').checkbox("refresh");
            rd=$('input:[name=radiob]:radio:checked').val();
            inc="i"+rd;
            var ch=1;
            var sl=parseInt(rd)+parseInt(ch);
            $("#slider").attr("min", sl).slider("refresh");   
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method name you are using in the first line of `checkIncrement()` is wrong.It should be `checkboxradio`

```
$('input:[name=radiob]:radio:checked').checkboxradio("refresh")
```

A demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/kvhFc/

Comment: I have made the correction, but now when i click on second button it is updated visually, but the previous button remains same visually. I think we need to refresh other buttons also (unchecked one's). How to do that?

Comment: Can you try commenting out that line and see how it works in that case?

Comment: in that case, when i click on the button it triggers the event but when i click it again then it updates visually. (after two clicks)

Comment: I created a jsfiddle out of the code you posted and it seems to be working fine.Here is the link for that.http://jsfiddle.net/kvhFc/. Where have you called the change handler for the radio buttons?.Please update the fiddle with the way you have written so that I can take a look into it.

Comment: I have used this code $('input:[name=radiob]').checkboxradio("refresh"); and its working fine. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

in Jquery mobile radio button like  this:

```
$(".iscfieldset input[type='radio']").checkboxradio().checkboxradio("refresh");
```

try this working fine for me